# Polymer, Cannot Get passed Ajax Data

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer

I want to ask about Polymer. When I tried to pass my data from ajax to child component, I cannot get the data at the child Component. It looks like the child component already rendered before the parent get the data from ajax. Here is my Code:

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="myId">
    <item-list></item-list>
    <search-track></search-track>
    <promo-banner styling="margin-left: 250px !important;margin-bottom: 50px !important; "></promo-banner>
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{data}}"<product-view data="{{data}}"></product-view></template>
    <product-recommendation></product-recommendation>
    <product-description></product-description>
    <info-pengiriman></info-pengiriman>
    <info-disclaimer></info-disclaimer>
    <mengapa-dekoruma></mengapa-dekoruma>
</template>
<iron-ajax
    id="requestProductData"
    url="/assets/json/dekoruma.json"
    params='{"type":"all"}'
    handle-as="json"
    on-response="handleResponse">
</iron-ajax>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "product-page",

        properties: {
            data: {
                type: Array
            },
            productData: {
                type: Object
            }
        },
        ready: function () {
            this.$.requestProductData.generateRequest();
        },
        handleResponse: function (data) {
            this.data = data.detail.response;
            console.log('id',this.id)
            for (var i = 0;i<this.data.produk.length;i++){
                if (this.data.produk[i].id == this.id){
                    this.productData = this.data.produk[i];
                }
            }
            console.log(this.productData)
            this.$.myId.render()
        },
        handleUrlName: function (url){
            return "../assets/image/"+url;
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `this.$.myId.render()`? Polymer/browser renders elements automatically.

Comment: Also you a missing `>` in `<template is="dom-if" if="{{data}}"`. Could it be a reason that `dom-if` does not work?